# Class 'Admin::class' not found (View:... in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, web

Whene i would right a name for a person who i have a secondly key he give me this probleme ,so i right this type of code in larvel 5 so i don't know this is a problem in laravel 8 when i would changed in more details or another problem for more explication this is my code  :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">Adress</th>
     <th scope="col">number</th>
       <th scope="col">admin name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  @if($administrations)
  @foreach($administrations as $administration)
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$administration->name}}</th>
      <td>{!!$administration->adress!!}</td>
      <td>{{$administration->number}}</td> 
      <td>{{$administration->admins->name}}</td> 
      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
  @endif
```

And this is a code for my controller :

```
 public function storefac(Request $request){
$this->validate($request,[
"name"=> 'required',
"number"=>'required',
"adress"=>'required',
]);
$id=Auth::user()->id;
$emps=new Administrations;
$emps->name=$request->input('name');
$emps->adress=$request->input('adress');
(integer)$emps->number=$request->input('number');
$emps->id_superAdmin=$id;
$emps->save();
return redirect()->back()->with('success','data saved');
```

And code for my two models ( admin and administration):

```
class Administrations extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'address',
            'number',
            'id_Admin'
    ];

   public function admin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Admin::class');
    }


class Admin extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'grade',
    'adress',
'number',
        'id_user'
    ];

 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class');
    }
    public function administrations ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Administrations::class');
    }
```

Comment: `::class` returns a string already, remove the `'`, as long as your model share namespace should work; `return $this->belongsTo(User::class);`

Comment: thak u i correct it but the same probleme

Answer (score 0):

Are Admin and Administration in the same file? If so they need to be in their own file. And I can see you don't close the Administrations class correctly. Also I can see that your foreign keys aren't compatible with laravel either you can rename them to 'user_id' and 'admin_id' or you can do this.

```
$this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'id_admin');
```

And

```
$this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user');
```